# Gitlab - ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator

Tags: gitlab

I have an gitlab-runner (as shell) which fails to upload to "coordinator" as I suspect is the gitlab server. It's a java project. Any seen this error before, or have suggestions on how to fix? Updated both gitlab server + runner to last version, but still same error.

Error message is:

```
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... failed  id=2926 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=wWcXeTqY
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against https://git.infosynergi.no/api/v4/jobs/2926/artifacts?artifact_format=gzip&artifact_type=junit: Post https://git.infosynergi.no/api/v4/jobs/2926/artifacts?artifact_format=gzip&artifact_type=junit: gzip.Write: non-Latin-1 header string id=2926 token=wWcXeTqY
FATAL: invalid argument                            
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer reduced amount uploaded of tests, which solved the issue.